# flutter_downloader, how do I get the values of url and filename from firebase into this flow and add to the list of download tasks?

Tags: android, flutter, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I want to pass the values like name and link in the below code's final variables dynamically i.e when onPressed is executed. Any help would be appreciated... I have separated the section using ----- below.

In the example below all files have their names and links hardcoded which is less efficient and I want to pass these values dynamically and only when a user clicks on the required button

```
import 'dart:isolate';
import 'dart:ui';
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:flutter_downloader/flutter_downloader.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

const debug = true;

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await FlutterDownloader.initialize(debug: debug);

  runApp(new MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final platform = Theme.of(context).platform;

    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(
        title: 'Downloader',
        platform: platform,
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  final TargetPlatform platform;

  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title, this.platform}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
final _documents = [
    {
      'name': 'Learning Android Studio',
      'link':
          'http://barbra-coco.dyndns.org/student/learning_android_studio.pdf'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Android Programming Cookbook',
      'link':
          'http://enos.itcollege.ee/~jpoial/allalaadimised/reading/Android-Programming-Cookbook.pdf'
    },
    {
      'name': 'iOS Programming Guide',
      'link':
          'http://darwinlogic.com/uploads/education/iOS_Programming_Guide.pdf'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Objective-C Programming (Pre-Course Workbook',
      'link':
          'https://www.bignerdranch.com/documents/objective-c-prereading-assignment.pdf'
    },
  ];

  final _images = [
    {
      'name': 'Arches National Park',
      'link':
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/60/The_Organ_at_Arches_National_Park_Utah_Corrected.jpg'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Canyonlands National Park',
      'link':
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/78/Canyonlands_National_Park%E2%80%A6Needles_area_%286294480744%29.jpg'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Death Valley National Park',
      'link':
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b2/Sand_Dunes_in_Death_Valley_National_Park.jpg'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Gates of the Arctic National Park and Preserve',
      'link':
          'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/e4/GatesofArctic.jpg'
    }
  ];

  final _videos = [
    {
      'name': 'Big Buck Bunny',
      'link':
          'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4'
    },
    {
      'name': 'Elephant Dream',
      'link':
          'http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4'
    }
  ];
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  List<_TaskInfo> _tasks;
  List<_ItemHolder> _items;
  bool _isLoading;
  bool _permissionReady;
  String _localPath;
  ReceivePort _port = ReceivePort();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _bindBackgroundIsolate();

    FlutterDownloader.registerCallback(downloadCallback);

    _isLoading = true;
    _permissionReady = false;

    _prepare();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _unbindBackgroundIsolate();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _bindBackgroundIsolate() {
    bool isSuccess = IsolateNameServer.registerPortWithName(
        _port.sendPort, 'downloader_send_port');
    if (!isSuccess) {
      _unbindBackgroundIsolate();
      _bindBackgroundIsolate();
      return;
    }
    _port.listen((dynamic data) {
      if (debug) {
        print('UI Isolate Callback: $data');
      }
      String id = data[0];
      DownloadTaskStatus status = data[1];
      int progress = data[2];

      final task = _tasks?.firstWhere((task) => task.taskId == id);
      if (task != null) {
        setState(() {
          task.status = status;
          task.progress = progress;
        });
      }
    });
  }

  void _unbindBackgroundIsolate() {
    IsolateNameServer.removePortNameMapping('downloader_send_port');
  }

  static void downloadCallback(
      String id, DownloadTaskStatus status, int progress) {
    if (debug) {
      print(
          'Background Isolate Callback: task ($id) is in status ($status) and process ($progress)');
    }
    final SendPort send =
        IsolateNameServer.lookupPortByName('downloader_send_port');
    send.send([id, status, progress]);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Builder(
          builder: (context) => _isLoading
              ? new Center(
                  child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
                )
              : _permissionReady
                  ? _buildDownloadList()
                  : _buildNoPermissionWarning()),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildDownloadList() => Container(
        child: ListView(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16.0),
          children: _items
              .map((item) => item.task == null
                  ? _buildListSection(item.name)
                  : DownloadItem(
                      data: item,
                      onItemClick: (task) {
                        _openDownloadedFile(task).then((success) {
                          if (!success) {
                            Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                                content: Text('Cannot open this file')));
                          }
                        });
                      },
                      onAtionClick: (task) {
                        if (task.status == DownloadTaskStatus.undefined) {
                          _requestDownload(task);
                        } else if (task.status == DownloadTaskStatus.running) {
                          _pauseDownload(task);
                        } else if (task.status == DownloadTaskStatus.paused) {
                          _resumeDownload(task);
                        } else if (task.status == DownloadTaskStatus.complete) {
                          _delete(task);
                        } else if (task.status == DownloadTaskStatus.failed) {
                          _retryDownload(task);
                        }
                      },
                    ))
              .toList(),
        ),
      );

  Widget _buildListSection(String title) => Container(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0, vertical: 8.0),
        child: Text(
          title,
          style: TextStyle(
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.blue, fontSize: 18.0),
        ),
      );

  Widget _buildNoPermissionWarning() => Container(
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Please grant accessing storage permission to continue -_-',
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueGrey, fontSize: 18.0),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 32.0,
              ),
              FlatButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    _checkPermission().then((hasGranted) {
                      setState(() {
                        _permissionReady = hasGranted;
                      });
                    });
                  },
                  child: Text(
                    'Retry',
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.blue,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 20.0),
                  ))
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );

  void _requestDownload(_TaskInfo task) async {
    task.taskId = await FlutterDownloader.enqueue(
        url: task.link,
        headers: {"auth": "test_for_sql_encoding"},
        savedDir: _localPath,
        showNotification: true,
        openFileFromNotification: true);
  }

  void _cancelDownload(_TaskInfo task) async {
    await FlutterDownloader.cancel(taskId: task.taskId);
  }

  void _pauseDownload(_TaskInfo task) async {
    await FlutterDownloader.pause(taskId: task.taskId);
  }

  void _resumeDownload(_TaskInfo task) async {
    String newTaskId = await FlutterDownloader.resume(taskId: task.taskId);
    task.taskId = newTaskId;
  }

  void _retryDownload(_TaskInfo task) async {
    String newTaskId = await FlutterDownloader.retry(taskId: task.taskId);
    task.taskId = newTaskId;
  }

  Future<bool> _openDownloadedFile(_TaskInfo task) {
    return FlutterDownloader.open(taskId: task.taskId);
  }

  void _delete(_TaskInfo task) async {
    await FlutterDownloader.remove(
        taskId: task.taskId, shouldDeleteContent: true);
    await _prepare();
    setState(() {});
  }

  Future<bool> _checkPermission() async {
    if (widget.platform == TargetPlatform.android) {
      final status = await Permission.storage.status;
      if (status != PermissionStatus.granted) {
        final result = await Permission.storage.request();
        if (result == PermissionStatus.granted) {
          return true;
        }
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    } else {
      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  Future<Null> _prepare() async {
    final tasks = await FlutterDownloader.loadTasks();

    int count = 0;
    _tasks = [];
    _items = [];

    _tasks.addAll(_documents.map((document) =>
        _TaskInfo(name: document['name'], link: document['link'])));

    _items.add(_ItemHolder(name: 'Documents'));
    for (int i = count; i < _tasks.length; i++) {
      _items.add(_ItemHolder(name: _tasks[i].name, task: _tasks[i]));
      count++;
    }

    _tasks.addAll(_images
        .map((image) => _TaskInfo(name: image['name'], link: image['link'])));

    _items.add(_ItemHolder(name: 'Images'));
    for (int i = count; i < _tasks.length; i++) {
      _items.add(_ItemHolder(name: _tasks[i].name, task: _tasks[i]));
      count++;
    }

    _tasks.addAll(_videos
        .map((video) => _TaskInfo(name: video['name'], link: video['link'])));

    _items.add(_ItemHolder(name: 'Videos'));
    for (int i = count; i < _tasks.length; i++) {
      _items.add(_ItemHolder(name: _tasks[i].name, task: _tasks[i]));
      count++;
    }

    tasks?.forEach((task) {
      for (_TaskInfo info in _tasks) {
        if (info.link == task.url) {
          info.taskId = task.taskId;
          info.status = task.status;
          info.progress = task.progress;
        }
      }
    });

    _permissionReady = await _checkPermission();

    _localPath = (await _findLocalPath()) + Platform.pathSeparator + 'Download';

    final savedDir = Directory(_localPath);
    bool hasExisted = await savedDir.exists();
    if (!hasExisted) {
      savedDir.create();
    }

    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  Future<String> _findLocalPath() async {
    final directory = widget.platform == TargetPlatform.android
        ? await getExternalStorageDirectory()
        : await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return directory.path;
  }
}

class DownloadItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final _ItemHolder data;
  final Function(_TaskInfo) onItemClick;
  final Function(_TaskInfo) onAtionClick;

  DownloadItem({this.data, this.onItemClick, this.onAtionClick});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.0, right: 8.0),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: data.task.status == DownloadTaskStatus.complete
            ? () {
                onItemClick(data.task);
              }
            : null,
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 64.0,
              child: Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Expanded(
                    child: Text(
                      data.name,
                      maxLines: 1,
                      softWrap: true,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
                    child: _buildActionForTask(data.task),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            data.task.status == DownloadTaskStatus.running ||
                    data.task.status == DownloadTaskStatus.paused
                ? Positioned(
                    left: 0.0,
                    right: 0.0,
                    bottom: 0.0,
                    child: LinearProgressIndicator(
                      value: data.task.progress / 100,
                    ),
                  )
                : Container()
          ].where((child) => child != null).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildActionForTask(_TaskInfo task) {
    if (task.status == DownloadTaskStatus.undefined) {
      return RawMaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {
          onAtionClick(task);
        },
        child: Icon(Icons.file_download),
        shape: CircleBorder(),
        constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 32.0, minWidth: 32.0),
      );
    } else if (task.status == DownloadTaskStatus.running) {
      return RawMaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {
          onAtionClick(task);
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.pause,
          color: Colors.red,
        ),
        shape: CircleBorder(),
        constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 32.0, minWidth: 32.0),
      );
    } else if (task.status == DownloadTaskStatus.paused) {
      return RawMaterialButton(
        onPressed: () {
          onAtionClick(task);
        },
        child: Icon(
          Icons.play_arrow,
          color: Colors.green,
        ),
        shape: CircleBorder(),
        constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 32.0, minWidth: 32.0),
      );
    } else if (task.status == DownloadTaskStatus.complete) {
      return Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          Text(
            'Ready',
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.green),
          ),
          RawMaterialButton(
            onPressed: () {
              onAtionClick(task);
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.delete_forever,
              color: Colors.red,
            ),
            shape: CircleBorder(),
            constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 32.0, minWidth: 32.0),
          )
        ],
      );
    } else if (task.status == DownloadTaskStatus.canceled) {
      return Text('Canceled', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red));
    } else if (task.status == DownloadTaskStatus.failed) {
      return Row(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
        children: [
          Text('Failed', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red)),
          RawMaterialButton(
            onPressed: () {
              onAtionClick(task);
            },
            child: Icon(
              Icons.refresh,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
            shape: CircleBorder(),
            constraints: BoxConstraints(minHeight: 32.0, minWidth: 32.0),
          )
        ],
      );
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}

class _TaskInfo {
  final String name;
  final String link;

  String taskId;
  int progress = 0;
  DownloadTaskStatus status = DownloadTaskStatus.undefined;

  _TaskInfo({this.name, this.link});
}

class _ItemHolder {
  final String name;
  final _TaskInfo task;

  _ItemHolder({this.name, this.task});
}
```